# How can I resolve "The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int' " - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, integer, arguments

I'm trying to fetch data Online Using HTTP GET with Flutter SDK. I'm trying with this code https://github.com/RaglandCodes/Flutter-basic-API/blob/master/lib/main.dart but it is showing an error about data type that's

**The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'**

> Here's Error part

```
new Card(
     child: new Container(
     child: new Text(data[index]['name']), //error red underlying with 'name'
     padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
     ),
```

> Here's my main.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new HomePage(),));
}

 class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
 }

 class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  String url="https://swapi.co/api/people/";
  List<String> data;

  /*onCreate*/
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    getJSONData(); //method
  }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return new Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
           title: Text("my JSON app")
       ),
       body: new ListView.builder(
        // itemCount: 1,
         //itemCount: data==null ? 0 :data.length ,
         itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,

         itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
           return new Container(
             child: new Center(
               child: new Column(
                 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, 
                 children: <Widget>[
                   new Card(
                     child: new Container(
                       child: new Text(data[index]['name']),
                       padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                     ),
                   )
                 ],
               ),
             ),
           );
         },
       ),
     );
   }

   /*method*/ //RT is Future<String>
  Future<String> getJSONData() async{
    var response =await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull(url),
      headers: {"Accept": "application/json"}
    );
   print(response.body);
   debugPrint(response.body);

    setState(() {
      var convertDataToJson= json.decode(response.body);
      data=convertDataToJson['results'];
    });

    return "Success";
  }
 }
```

Comment: `data` is of type `List<String>`.  What is `data[index]['name']` supposed to be?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to set `data` variable to `List` type.

That's should work:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new HomePage(),
  ));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String url = "https://swapi.co/api/people/";
  List data;

  /*onCreate*/
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    getJSONData(); //method
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("my JSON app")),
      body: new ListView.builder(
        // itemCount: 1,
        //itemCount: data==null ? 0 :data.length ,
        itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,

        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new Container(
            child: new Center(
              child: new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Card(
                    child: new Container(
                      child: new Text(data[index]['name'] ?? ''),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  /*method*/ //RT is Future<String>
  Future<String> getJSONData() async {
    var response = await http
        .get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    print(response.body);
    debugPrint(response.body);

    setState(() {
      var convertDataToJson = json.decode(response.body);
      data = convertDataToJson['results'];
    });

    return "Success";
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer would be more complete if you explained why

Comment: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.

Answer (score 81):

That's worked for me

```
http.get(Uri.https('https://swapi.co', 'api/people'));
```

or

```
http.get(Uri.parse('https://swapi.co/api/people'));
```

Comment: This is a valid answer for those using `http: 0.13.0` and above. Here is the changelog which mentions this as a breaking change: https://pub.dev/packages/http/changelog#0130-nullsafety0

Answer (score 35):

If you add `.toString()` the error will disappear:

`Text(data[index]['name'].toString())`

good

Answer (score 15):

The reason is that **http.get** can't work with strings anymore. You need to use **Uri to parse the HTTP address.**

I had the same issue which I fixed it with this approach:

```
var url = Uri.parse("https://your_api_link");
```

then call it like this (attaching the http):

```
http.Response response = await http.get(url);
```

This should work.

Comment: Well, I don't really know the reason, maybe `String` could no longer handle URL values due to the async pattern in retrieving the url data. But I think someone else could have a better reason here.

Answer (score 4):

```js
var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/9193372) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 4):

**That's worked for me**

```
 http.Response respobse= await 
      http.get(Uri.parse("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos"));
    
    Uri.parse(json Url);
```

use this.

Answer (score 3):

**This one will work**

```
String url = '$api?lat=$latitude&lon=$longitude&APPID=$appId';
 http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
```

Answer (score 3):

if you will simply add .toSting() to your lists like below it will remove the error.

```
new Card(
     child: new Container(
     child: new Text(data[index]['name'].toString()), //This line
     padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
),
```

Comment: Such answer already exists

Answer (score 2):

That's worked for me

```
void getData() async {
  Response response = await 
  http.get(Uri.parse("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"));
  print(response.body);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add "**.toString()**" the error will disappear:

```
new Text(data[index]['name'].toString()),
```

So:

```
new Card(
     child: new Container(
     child: new Text(data[index]['name'].toString()), //you'll no longer get an error
     padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
     ),
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use this way

```
Future<http.Response> fetchAlbum() {return http.get(Uri.https('jsonplaceholder.typicode.com', 'albums/1'));}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using pdf package
your want to delete  `import 'dart:html';`
and use  `import 'dart:io';`
It's worked for me,
Have a good day  :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<String> getSWData() async 
{

   // String res = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    http.Response res = await http.get(url);

     // var res =   await http.get(Uri.https('http://3.255.7.222:8084/sipService/supplerMaster/v1/getSupplierMasterList', 'api/people'));

    var resBody = json.decode(res.body);
    setState(() {
      data = resBody;
    });
    print(resBody);
    return "Sucess";
  }
```