# Flutter throwing error when used the get method in the http package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

When I am trying to get data from the internet to use it in my app via the get method provided by the flutter http package it throws this error - *The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'*.  This is my code

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';



class Loading extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingState createState() => _LoadingState();
}

class _LoadingState extends State<Loading> {
  @override
  void getData() async {
   http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
  }

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text("some text"),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I resolve "The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int' " - Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55995791/how-can-i-resolve-the-argument-type-string-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter)

Comment: Thanks for your your reply but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First argument of http package request method is `Uri` type, So you have to change your code to this:

```
  void getData() async {
    final requestUrl = Uri.parse("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
    http.get(requestUrl)
  }
```