# The argument type 'String?' cant be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. I am trying to save the user information which we get from google sign in

Tags: flutter, dart

```
UserCredential result= await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);

User? userDetails = result.user;

if(result!= null)
{
    SharedPreferenceHelper().saveUserEmail(userDetails.email);
    SharedPreferenceHelper().saveUserId(userDetails.uid);
    SharedPreferenceHelper().saveDisplayName(userDetails.displayName);
    SharedPreferenceHelper().saveUserProfileUrl(userDetails.photoURL);
}
```

This was my code, how can I reslove it?

I tried replacing '.' with '?.' and '!.' however it is not working

Comment: Please [edit] your code with the complete Traceback.

Comment: "_I tried replacing '.' with '?.' and '!.' .."_ Please [edit] your question to show your attempt.

Comment: Does [How can I resolve "The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int' " - Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55995791/10157127) answer your question?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh You have enough rep; Why not _vote_ to close the question?

Comment: Yes @mendelg, my single vote will close the question and the link I've provided will solve the issue, but some beginner lost the spirit of coding, I considered this case .

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I got you. But, on the other hand, StackOverflow isn't meant for these types of questions, It's a _resource_ of a bunch of questions, where you search and find questions. Also, the OP should of done a lot more research before asking their question

Comment: @MendelG you are right.  I check user's reputation (mainly if I find `New contributor`), I include the necessary links, like to make [question better](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I like to welcome newcomers on Stack Overflow and try to provide a friendly environment. Hope you've got my point.

Answer (score 3):

Try to handle with the null operator and give some default value if they are null.

```
  UserCredential result= await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    
    User? userDetails = result.user;
    
    if(result!= null)
    {
        SharedPreferenceHelper().saveUserEmail(userDetails?.email??'');
        SharedPreferenceHelper().saveUserId(userDetails?.uid??'');
        SharedPreferenceHelper().saveDisplayName(userDetails?.displayName??'');
        SharedPreferenceHelper().saveUserProfileUrl(userDetails?.photoURL??'');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if the value of userDetails.email, userDetails.uid,userDetails.displayName etc is null try this

```
SharedPreferenceHelper().saveUserEmail(userDetails.email!);
SharedPreferenceHelper().saveUserId(userDetails.uid!);
SharedPreferenceHelper().saveDisplayName(userDetails.displayName!);
SharedPreferenceHelper().saveUserProfileUrl(userDetails.photoURL!);
```

it will solve your problem if not then let me know

Answer (score 0):

##### Explanation:

This is happening because you have declared `userDetails` as `User?` which means `userDetails can be null` but `saveUserEmail()` takes in type of `String` which cannot be `null`

Try with

```
// When you are sure that userDetails can never be null
SharedPreferenceHelper().saveUserEmail(userDetails.email!);
```

or

```
// When you want to store '' if the email is null
SharedPreferenceHelper().saveUserEmail(userDetails?.email ?? '');
```

or

```
User userDetails; // This option here is not possible because result.user returns type of User?
SharedPreferenceHelper().saveUserEmail(userDetails.email!);
```

Note: Follow the same steps for `userDetails.uid`,`userDetails.photoUrl`,`userDetails.displayName`