# Flutter: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

Error is coming at line 44 and 45 i.e at if (regExpPattern.hasMatch(settings.name))
and at this line final firstMatch = regExpPattern.firstMatch(settings.name).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(

     title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    initialRoute: '/screen',
     onGenerateRoute:RouteConfiguration.onGenerateRoute,
      /* routes:{
        '/':(context) => const FirstScreen(),
        '/second':(context) => const SecondScreen(),
        '/third':(context) => const ThirdPage(),
      }, */
  ),
    );
  }
class Path{
  const Path(this.pattern,this.builder);
  final String pattern;
 final Widget Function(BuildContext, String) builder;
}

class RouteConfiguration {
  
  static List<Path> paths = [
    Path(
      r'^' + ArticlePage.baseRoute + r'/([\w-]+)$',
      (context, match) => Article.getArticlePage(match),
    ),
    Path(
      r'^' + SecondScreen.route,
      (context, match) => const SecondScreen(),
    ),
    Path(
      r'^' + FirstScreen.route,
      (context, match) => const FirstScreen(),
    ),
  ];
  static Route<dynamic>? onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    for (Path path in paths) {
      final regExpPattern = RegExp(path.pattern);
      if (regExpPattern.hasMatch(settings.name)) {
        final firstMatch = regExpPattern.firstMatch(settings.name);
        final match = (firstMatch?.groupCount == 1) ? firstMatch?.group(1) : null;
        return MaterialPageRoute<void>(
          builder: (context) => path.builder(context, match!),
          settings: settings,
        );
      }
    }
return null;
  }
}

// In a real application this would probably be some kind of database interface.
const List<Article> articles = [
  Article(
    title: 'A very interesting article',
    slug: 'a-very-interesting-article',
  ),
  Article(
    title: 'Newsworthy news',
    slug: 'newsworthy-news',
  ),
  Article(
    title: 'RegEx is cool',
    slug: 'regex-is-cool',
  ),
];

class Article {
  const Article({required this.title, required this.slug});

  final String title;
  final String slug;

  static Widget getArticlePage(String slug) {
    for (Article article in articles) {
      if (article.slug == slug) {
        return ArticlePage(article: article);
      }
    }
    return const UnknownArticle();
  }
}
    // If no match was found, we let [WidgetsApp.onUnknownRoute] handle it.
  class ArticlePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ArticlePage({Key? key, required this.article}) : super(key: key);

  static const String baseRoute = '/article';
  static String Function(String slug) routeFromSlug =
      (String slug) => '$baseRoute/$slug';

  final Article article;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(article.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(article.title),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: const Text('Go back!'),
            ),
               ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
 class UnknownArticle extends StatelessWidget {
  const UnknownArticle({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Unknown article'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text('Unknown article'),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: const Text('Go back!'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
    static const String route = '/';

  const FirstScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('First Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
          },
          child: const Text('Launch screen'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String route="/second";
  const SecondScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Second Screen'),
      ),
       body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            for (Article article in articles)
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                    ArticlePage.routeFromSlug(article.slug),
                  );
                },
                child: Text(article.title),
              ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Navigate back to the home screen by popping the current route
                // off the stack.
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: const Text('Go back!'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      
    );
  
  }
}
class ThirdPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ThirdPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Third Screen")
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');

            
          },
          child: const Text("Go back!"),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error is coming at line 44 and 45 i.e at  if (regExpPattern.hasMatch(settings.name))  and at line final firstMatch = regExpPattern.firstMatch(settings.name)

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55995791/10157127) answer your question?

Comment: yeah by adding toString() the error is gone.But the  output is not coming,it showing null exception like that

Answer (score 0):

Analyser displays this error because `name` field of `RouteSettings` has type `String?` but `RegExpMatch? firstMatch(String input)` accepts only non-nullable `String` arguments.

You should update your logic to handle the case when `settings.name == null`